# Get specific value while parsing JSON with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following JSON:

```
[  
   {  
      "A":"Lorem Ipsum ",
      "B":"Lorem Ipsum ",
      "C":"Lorem Ipsum ",
      "D":"Lorem Ipsum ",
      "E":"Lorem Ipsum ",
      "F":"Lorem Ipsum ",
      "G":301,
      "H":[  
         {  
            "Lorem Ipsum ":4,
            "Lorem Ipsum ":20,
            "Lorem Ipsum":0
         },
         {  
            "Lorem Ipsum ":5,
            "Lorem Ipsum ":19.2,
            "Lorem Ipsum ":0.8
         },
         {  
            "Lorem Ipsum ":1,
            "Lorem Ipsum ":8,
            "Lorem Ipsum ":4
         },
         {  
            "Lorem Ipsum ":3,
            "Lorem Ipsum ":14.2,
            "Lorem Ipsum ":5.8
         },
         {  
            "Lorem Ipsum ":2,
            "Lorem Ipsum ":20,
            "Lorem Ipsum ":0
         }
      ],
      "I":[  

      ],
      "J":[  

      ],
      "20-01-2014":20,
      "27-01-2014":19.2,
      "30-12-2013":8,
      "13-01-2014":14.2,
      "06-01-2014":20,
      "K":"81.40"
   },
   {  
      "reportKey":"something"
   }
]
```

I'd like to get the `reportKey` value and then remove it from the file. But first I need to access it and my code doesn't seem to work:

```
final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readValue(rawContentParameters, JsonNode.class);

logger.info("ExportController : generatesExportExcel : parameters: {}", jsonNode.get("reportKey").textValue());
```

but I'm getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. Why?

**SOLUTION:**

```
final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode rootNode = objectMapper.readValue(rawContentParameters, JsonNode.class);

logger.info("ExportController : generatesExportExcel : parameters: {}", rootNode.get(rootNode.size() - 1).get("reportKey").textValue());
```

Comment: does `objectMapper.readValue(rawContentParameters, JsonNode.class)` return null?

Comment: No it doesn't. It returns the full content of the JSON file.

Comment: Try `jsonNode.get(1).get("reportKey").textValue()`.

Comment: It doesn't work, I get the same error message.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ug8KVqg9

Comment: I think there is another problem.  Try comment out your code (3 lines).

Comment: You were right. See answers below and updated original post. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are accessing the root `JsonNode` as if it were an object, but it's wrapped in an array.  You need to extract the second object from the array before you can access `reportKey`:

```
JsonNode array = objectMapper.readValue(rawContentParameters, JsonNode.class);
JsonNode object = array.get(1);
String reportKey = object.get("reportKey").textValue();
logger.info("ExportController : generatesExportExcel : parameters: {}", reportKey);
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I'm getting the same error. Could it be something else, coming from the JSON file?

Comment: @Q3SanD apologies - was getting the wrong item from the array.  I have updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: I know. I didn't mention it but I corrected it myself. However it still doesn't work.  But thanks for your input!

Comment: I'm sorry, you guys were all right. I forgot that there were several arrays before getting to the `reportKey` value. See original post to see what I changed.

Answer (score 2):

First take second element on the list.

```
jsonNode.get(1).get("reportKey")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` from [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/) library :

```
//instantiate your json array (e.g. from a string, or a file)
//String s = "[...]";
String s = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(yourFile));
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(s);

//get the reportKey value:
json.get(1).get("reportKey");

//removing it:
//removing all the node: {"reportKey":"something"}
json.remove(1);
//removing only "reportKey":"something" and keeping {}:
json.get(1).remove("reportKey");
```